# Inserting one list into another list in java?

Tags: java

I have the below java code:

```
List<SomePojo> list = new ArrayList<SomePojo>();
//add 100 SomePojo objects to list.
```

Now list has 100 objects.

If I create one more instance as below:

```
List<SomePojo> anotherList = new ArrayList<SomePojo>();
anotherList.addAll(list);
```

Now, how many objects will be in memory: 100 or 200 objects?

In the line below, are objects being added or only references?

```
anotherList.addAll(list);
```

If I make any change to `list`, do the same changes reflect to `anotherList` and vice-versa?

Comment: Mind that I rolled back the original question, because your edits missed the whole point of the question itself.

Comment: The issue is that this is no longer a question, and does not make any sense at all ;)

Comment: please this question needs edit, it does'nt make sense.

Comment: This question needs moderator attention, looks like due to edits, the question is no longer there.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

An object is only once in memory. Your first addition to `list` just adds the object references.

`anotherList.addAll` will also just add the references. So still only 100 objects in memory.

If you change `list` by adding/removing elements, `anotherList` won't be changed. But if you change any object in `list`, then it's content will be also changed, when accessing it from `anotherList`, because the same reference is being pointed to from both lists.

Comment: How can clear ore remove another list reference?  
for example 
List<String > a=new ArrayList<>(); 
List<String> b=new ArrayList<>(); 
a.add("one"); 
a.add("two"); 
a.add("Three);

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Maybe you should just post a separate question on SO.

Answer (score 14):

100, it will hold the same references. Therefore if you make a change to a specific object in the `list`, it will affect the same object in `anotherList`.

Adding or removing objects in any of the list will not affect the other.

`list` and `anotherList` are two different instances, they only hold the same references of the objects "inside" them.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. if i add/remove any object in list, does same change is reflected to otherlist?

Comment: no it won't affect. list and anotherList are two different instances, they only hold the same references of the objects "inside" them.

Answer (score 6):

Citing the official javadoc of `List.addAll`:

```
Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of
this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified
collection's iterator (optional operation).  The behavior of this
operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while
the operation is in progress.  (Note that this will occur if the
specified collection is this list, and it's nonempty.)
```

So you will copy the references of the objects in `list` to `anotherList`. Any method that does not operate on the referenced objects of `anotherList` (such as removal, addition, sorting) is local to it, and therefore will not influence `list`.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from the **Java API** for **addAll(collection c)** in Interface **List** [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

*"Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's iterator (optional operation)."*

You you will have as much object as you have in both lists - the number of objects in your first list plus the number of objects you have in your second list - in your case 100.

Answer (score 0):

no... Once u have executed the statement anotherList.addAll(list) and after that if u change some list data it does not carry to another list