# adding a list of one type to a list of another type

Tags: java

I have my first list as

```
List<A> a
```

I have another list as

```
List<X.Y.Z> b
```

How do I add first list to the second one ?

I tried casting -

```
b.add(List<X.Y.Z>)a) - did not work
```

Tried adding through iteration of first list - did not work

definitely missed something ?

Comment: b is expecting something of type X.Y.Z and your trying to pass it an object of type List

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273440/adding-one-list-to-another-list-in-java

Comment: @Naveen Those are of not sametype.So add All wont work here i guess :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there is an Inheritance relationship between `A` and `X.Y.Z` you *cannot* have them in the same container because they are not of the same *type*

You can use the generic superclass Object as the type of the `List` and this will work.

Comment: the only one who mention inheritance +1

Comment: Thanks all for the answer...I am writing a different method for this conversion, as I am going to use it several times...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as the reference types for both collections are different. The only way items from one `List` can be merged with those from another is if they both are of type `List<Object>` or the types themselves are identical (or at least derived from the same type).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because of `type` of `List<>`

```
X.Y.Z != A
```

You can  use `List<Object>`, to which you can `add()` anything.Even though you added like that

you would have to cast each one back,while getting back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast list a as the same type as list b so that they are the same type of object. Check out [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

It should also be noted that if you want to add the elements of `List<A> a` to `List<X.Y.Z> b` (which I assume is your intent), rather than the `List<A> a` itself as an element, you should use the `addAll()` method, not the `add()` method.  But again, this won't work unless `A` is a subclass of `X.Y.Z`, and if `A` is a super class of `X.Y.Z` then casting the `A` variable will only work if it is an instance `X.Y.Z`.

Answer (score 0):

Either you use `List<Object>`, to which you can add anything, or you write a method somewhere to convert an object of type `A` to `X.Y.Z`.

Notice that, if you use `List<Object>`, you'll need to cast the object to the desired class when you get it:

```
List<Object> myList = new List<Object>;
// ...
A myObject = (A) myList.get(0);
X.Y.Z otherObject = (X.Y.Z) myList.get(1);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following case

```
    List<Integer> l1=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> l2=new ArrayList<>();

    l1.add(2);
    l2.addAll((List<String>)l1);
```

you are trying to do the same thing. here you can't cast integer list to string list.

Same way you can't cast A type list to X.Y.Z. type.