# How to clear the temp list reference after addAll original list in android

Tags: java, android

*emphasized text*How can change, clear or remove another list reference? for example, I have two lists named as listA and ListB and ListA have 3 items. Now I addAll items listA to listB after that I change anyone item in listB. it's changed in listA too. but  I don't want to change the listA.

```
I'm trying in android studio language is JAVA.

List<StringModel> listA=new List<>();
listA.add("One");
listA.add("Two");
listA.add("Three");

List<StringModel> listB=new List<>();
listB.addAll(listA);

listB.get(0).set("1");
```

Now listB is changed and listA also changed. But I don't want to change in listA original list. Like that clear and remove function also working.

after the search, reference is not clear for a duplicate list.

[Adding one list to another list in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273440/adding-one-list-to-another-list-in-java/11273482?noredirect=1#comment101708732_11273482)

I expect output to handle two lists in different reference.

Comment: First thing is List is an interface you can not instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you are referring to ArrayList in this situation:

```
ArrayList<String> listA=new ArrayList<String>();
listA.add("One");
listA.add("Two");
listA.add("Three");

ArrayList<String> listB=new ArrayList<String>();
listB.addAll(listA);
```

This would be valid code. If we use class String then we cannot change an element from the list since strings are immutable, the only option is to delete it from list or add another.

What I suppose you are asking is why the state is mutable in case we create an `ArrayList<ClassA>` ?

The answer comes from how variables interact with classes. For example let's say you want to create a new object of ClassA:

```
class ClassA {
  int x = 5;
}
```

`ClassA foo = new ClassA()`

In such situation foo contains **reference** to a object ClassA that was allocated in memory, then we can do something like:

```
ClassA bar = foo
bar.x = 10
```

If you print foo.x, you will observe that the value is 10, since you point to the same object in memory. Now when you add elements to the ArrayList you should understand that you are adding references to objects but not actual values and when you change value of field from listB that points to same object as in listA it changes values of course.

The solution to your problem is making sure you use immutable objects, or have a copy constructor that generates a new object with the same values as the original one.