# Merge an List of Object and an Object to a new array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, collections

I have `List<BigInteger> sample1 = Lists.newArrayList(BIGINTEGER1, BIGINTEGER2,BIGINTEGER3);`

I have to create new `List` `sample2` with one more value `BIGINTEGER4` along with `sample1` list:

How can I do that?

Comment: what's wrong with spending some time learning how lists work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting one list into another list in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273440/inserting-one-list-into-another-list-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new ArrayList, and pass the other list in the constructor - the contents from the other list will then be passed/copied into the new:

```java
List<BigInteger> sample2 = new ArrayList<>(sample1);
sample2.add(BIGINTEGER4);
```

Comment: In a ENUM 'm trying to do that.. not in normal code

Comment: @Ranjana I don't understand exactly, what do you mean by `In a ENUM`?